# Define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers

Tags: sorting, scheme, comparison

I'm having trouble figuring out how to sort out the 2 biggest numbers and return them into the sum of squares procedure. I am struggling to write the code out in Scheme's syntax. I'm trying to write it as cleanly as possible, and I keep running circles in my head and on paper trying to do so. the book describes thinking "procedurally" and I think I'm having trouble with that aspect.

The book provides code for the sum-of-squares and square procedures. I would include my pseudo code but I'm severely lost. Here is the code the book provides:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (sum-of-squares x y)
  (+ (square x) (square y)))
```

How to define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers?

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SICP Exercise 1.3 request for comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161666/sicp-exercise-1-3-request-for-comments)

Answer (score 3):

> How to define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers?

First you need a name for the procedure. Let's called it `sum-of-squares-two-largest`.

```
(define (sum-of-squares-two-largest x y z)
   ...)
```

It can make use of the `sum-of-squares` function, but it needs to find the two largest numbers out of x,y,z first.

One way to do this would be to get rid of the smallest number. You could define a helper procedure `smallest? a b c` that checks that a is the smallest of the 3 numbers by doing `(and (<= a b) (<= a c))`.

```
(define (sum-of-squares-two-largest x y z)
   (if (smallest? x y z)
       (sum-of-squares y z)
       (if (smallest? y x z)
           ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the code for `min-of-three`. Its *negative* (as in photography) is what you need:

```
(define (negative-min-of-three a b c)
   (if (<= a b)
       (if (<= a c)
           (..... b ... c .....)
           (..... a ... b .....))
       (if (<= 
   ..........
```

You can complete the code, and rename it. The clock is ticking!

Comment: in case a downvoter was put off by the last sentence in this answer, it was a reference to OP's profile's statement, intended as an encouragement. I have no idea otherwise what could have been the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I created two methods to get the largest and the one in the middle for the time being.

```
(define (largest x y z)
  (cond ((and (> x y) (> x z)) x)
        ((and (> y x) (> y z)) y)
        (else z))
)

(define (mid x y z)
  (cond ((and (> x y) (< x z)) x)
        ((and (> y x) (< y z)) y)
        (else z))
)

(define (square a)
  (* a a)
)

(define (sum-of-two-largest x y z)
  (+ (square (largest x y z)) (square (mid x y z)))
)

(sum-of-two-largest -12 -4 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The hard part of this is, if you're reading [SICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs#:%7E:text=Structure%20and%20Interpretation%20of%20Computer%20Programs%20(SICP)%20is%20a%20computer,Jay%20Sussman%20with%20Julie%20Sussman.&text=It%20was%20formerly%20used%20as,electrical%20engineering%20and%20computer%20science.) book, finding the 2nd largest number of the three. You can observe, if we let c < b < a, that:

```
a = max(a, b) gives the largest of the two numbers
b = max(c, b) gives the largest of the two smaller numbers
```

But how do we get the variable b on the second line. It can so happen that a is the smaller of the two? We can observe that:

```
b = min(a, b)
```

If we substitute min(a, b) for b in the max function on the third line, we get:

```
b = max(c, min(a, b))
```

This strategy is implemented in the following code, using only the constructs introduced in the book so far:

```lisp
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (max a b) (if (> a b) a b))

(define (min a b) (if (< a b) a b))

(define (sum-of-squares-two-largest a b c)
   (+ (square (max a b)) (square (max c (min a b)))))

(sum-of-squares-two-largest 1 2 3)
(sum-of-squares-two-largest 1 2 1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).